# Using Gimp to batch convert images to another format in Windows

Tags: conversion, batch, file-format, gimp

As implied by the title, does anybody know how to use the gimp-console-[version].exe program to batch convert images between formats (with default settings) in Windows ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Better than Gimp or Irfanview is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).

For instance, try:

```
mogrify -format jpg *.png
```

Comment: Also `mogrify` will overwrite the original images, use `convert` to make new files in the desired format.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! ImageMagick got automatically installed when I installed Zbar (a barcode reader, it Depended on ImageMagick,) but I didn't realize how useful this was! Thank you so much!

Comment: Please be aware, that in many cases Gimp generates smaller images than imagemagick, so if you are going for size, check gimp batch mode as well.

Comment: If you only need to do this rarely and have Gimp installed for image editing anyway but don't have ImageMagick installed then doing this with Gimp makes perfect sense. Also if you don't have permissions to install software.

Comment: @DaveParillo In this case it's not. quote: `unless you change the file suffix with the -format option` http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php

Comment: its does not work for latest 8086 windows version

Comment: seems to work, but for the latest version it's all included in one tool so the command line is `magick mogrify -format jpg *.png`. Also, despite saying it  added itself to the path variable it didn't seem to work without going to the specific install folder.

Comment: The full command for me was: magick mogrify -format jpg *.bmp

Comment: Does this convert `.jpg` to `.png`, or is it vice versa?

Comment: Still works in 2021 but as others mentioned the command has changed and now requires 'magick'. It also created copies rather than overwriting the files for me

Comment: trying to convert pdfs to jpeg with imagemagick i cannot confirm this to be the "better option". the results look worse and lack proper color mapping on top. Not sure if there is ghostscript or imagemagick to blame for it though.

Answer (score 10):

Put the following in `~/.gimp-<YOURVERSION>/scripts/myconvert.scm`:

```
(define (myconvert in_filename out_filename)
    (let* (
            (image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE in_filename in_filename)))
            (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image)))
        )
        (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable out_filename out_filename)
        (gimp-image-delete image)
    )
)
```

Then, you can run something like this to convert all the files in the current directory to JPGs:

```
for A in * ; do gimp -i -b "(myconvert \"$A\" \"$A.jpg\")" -b '(gimp-quit 0)' ; done
```

Comment: For me (running Debian GNU/Linux), the folder was ```~/.config/GIMP/2.10/scripts```.

Answer (score 6):

There is also a wizard based batch processor available:

[DBP (David's Batch Processor)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimpdbpplugin/) for GIMP

[image]

Comment: I've tried so many different ways to batch convert a bunch of DDS files to another file format, and this is the only way that's worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: There's also bimp (http://registry.gimp.org/node/26259)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, nothing happens when I copy this to the plug-ins folder. Also, the link to the website on SourceForge is dead.

Answer (score 4):

Is using [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) not an option?  I keep both GIMP and Irfanview installed for precisely this reason...GIMP for image editing and Irfanview for batch conversion.

Comment: Irfanview is named for its author, Irfan Skiljan.  Irfanview is pronounced "EarfanView".  See http://www.irfanview.com/main_about.htm for more.

Comment: There's this to keep in mind for Irfanview, though: "IrfanView is provided as freeware, but only for private, non-commercial use (that means at home). IrfanView is free for educational use (schools, universities, museums and libraries) and for use in charity or humanitarian organisations. If you intend to use IrfanView at your place of business or for commercial purposes, please register and purchase it." http://www.irfanview.com/eula.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like this is only available on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

> *does anybody know how to use the gimp-console-[version].exe program to batch convert images between formats (with default settings) in Windows ?*

The `gimp-console-[version].exe` uses a language called ["scheme"](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Scheme/) for command interpretation.  Scripts often are found ending in the `.scm` extension.

Scheme's hard to batch to the console due to nuances with quotes as can be observed [here](https://superuser.com/a/537492/443147), but it's possible.

Here's an example which converts all `.svg` files in the current directory to `.png` files using batch.  It also will look in the registry for the Gimp executable and calculate the path to the command-line version.

```
@echo off

set resolution=72
set width=400
set height=600

REM Find Gimp in the registry
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKCR\GIMP2.svg\shell\open\command" /ve 2^>^&1^|find "REG_"') do @set gimp=%%b

REM Calculate console exe
set gimp=%gimp:gimp-=gimp-console-%

REM Isolate exe
for %%i in (%gimp%) do (
    @set gimp=%%i
    goto :found
)

:found
echo Found Gimp console: %gimp%

REM Process files (change to "for /r %%i" for recursion)
for %%i in (*.svg) do (
    echo - Converting [ %%i --^> %%~ni.png ] ^(%width%x%height%@%resolution%^)
    %gimp% -i -b "(let* ((image (car (file-svg-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE \"%%i\" \"\" 72 (- 0 400) (- 0 600) 0))) (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image)))) (plug-in-autocrop RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable) (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable \"%%~ni.png\" \"%%~ni.png\") (gimp-image-delete image))" -b "(gimp-quit 0)"
)
```

Note, this final command line can be adopted to other platforms by using single quotes around the entire scheme command and using bare double-quotes within.  Tested on Gimp 2.10.18, 2.10.14.

This answer uses code extraced from a `.scm` file from a web-archived article from [Matthew Gates 2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20140214102644/http://porpoisehead.net/mysw/index.php?pgid=gimp_svg) titled "Gimp SVG to Raster Script".

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest [BIMP](https://alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/) , an EXCELLENT GMIP plugin, with powerful Batch image manipulation function and brief UI.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Windows GUI to perform batch modifications on images (including file format conversion)

http://www.imagebatch.org/

Hope that helps someone out there!

Comment: This will not convert from PSD

Answer (score 0):

I am going to fall into the camp of using the right tool for the job and I have both Irfanview, and ImageMagick installed, and agree that both are fantastic tools. However let me throw in one more option for posterity. I don't use XnView on a regular basis, but keep a copy of the portable version around to keep on my usb so that I have a powerful easy to use very capable image tool available when I'm out and about. The beauty of the portable version is that you can use it and if you don't like it just delete the install directory. It along with dozens of other free and open source portable applications is available at 
http://portableapps.com/
or specifically
http://portableapps.com/news/2009-12-06_-_xnview_portable_1.97
The installer will create a directory that contains everything necessary to run the program. Just go to that directory, start the EXE, give it a test. As stated above, when you get tired of it just delete the whole directory. They all run just like that from a USB stick as well. I have about 80 apps I carry around with me and use on public or shared PC's.

Comment: Similar to Irfanview, XnView has some usage restrictions: "XnView is provided as FREEWARE (NO Adware, NO Spyware) for private or educational use (including non-profit organizations)." - see http://www.xnview.com/en/xnview/

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not really answering the question here I have alternative solution that has worked for me quite well and works from within the GIMP.

Keep in mind this might not be best solution for very large number of images.

[Export Layers plugin for GIMP](http://registry.gimp.org/node/28268) (I am not an author of this plug-in)

> - uses native dialogs for file format export procedures to adjust file    format settings.
> - uses layer names as filenames for the exported images.
> - supports layer groups and optionally treats them as folders.
> - can optionally export only layers whose file extension matches specified file format.
> - can use file extensions in layer names as file formats
> - can use layers with names in [square brackets] as background layers

1. First make sure you have **GIMP 2.8 or higher** (I confirm it works on 2.8.14)
2. Download the plug-in (*make sure it saves as file with **.py extension***)
3. Paste the plug-in into the ***GIMP_INSTALLATION_FOLDER\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins***
4. Import your images *as layers* (*File > Open as layers*).
5. Select *File > Export Layers.. or Export Layers To*
6. Dialogue window will pop up with export options that look similar to any other GIMP dialogue window and are very self descriptive.

NOTE: If you paste the plug-in make sure GIMP is not working, if it is restart it.