# Converting multiple files to dds on gimp

Tags: gimp, dds

I need to convert multiple images to dds on gimp but since there are more than a hundred of them, i don't want to do it one by one. What i'm looking for is a way to convert them with the specific options i used on gimp. I searched for it on the internet and i couldn't find anything close to my problem. I hope someone can give a clear answer or i'll start converting them one by one which will take hours i guess. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "dds"?

Comment: @tapped-out, an image format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Gimp to batch convert images to another format in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/77429/using-gimp-to-batch-convert-images-to-another-format-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) if you need a batch conversion from or to DDS format. Latest version (currently is 6.8.7-4) support DDS format for both read and write (sse [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php)).

The syntax is very simple, you can convert a file at once:

```
convert myfile.png myfile.dds
```

Or you can convert all the files with a single command (assuming your files are png, for example):

```
mogrify -format dds *.png
```