# How to convert PSD to JPG or PNG on Linux with Gimp CLI/batch mode (or other server-side tool)?

Tags: command-line, conversion, gimp, jpeg, psd

I've been working on a theoretically simple web service to convert PSD or AI files to jpeg, png or some web-compatible format.

I was able to successfully use [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org)'s `convert -flatten sample.ai sample-ai.jpg` command, but consistently getting "invalid header" for various attempts using PhotoShop PSDs. I'm assuming ImageMagick prefers it's own or GIMP-saved PSD files, though perhaps I'm missing something there.

Also tried installing NConvert, but had problems with glibc version on client's CentOS 5.8, which I'm not permitted to change.

In any case, [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org) seems to have good PSD support. More than enough to flatten an image and save it. They've also recently updated their PSD parser. I've seen a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/77429/using-gimp-to-batch-convert-images-to-another-format-in-windows) but

1. that's on windows,
2. they didn't really answer anything for GIMP,
3. neither convert nor mogrify works for me

`mogrify: Improper image header 'Test1.psd'.`

So, does anyone know how to write a conversion script in Gimp via command line? I'm looking at [this article](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/) trying to figure out the commands, but I think my trouble is I don't know ScriptFu worth anything.

It would also be tremendously helpful if I can echo back the dimensions of the original PSD, but I can get these from the resulting file fairly easily with a second step.

Comment: Interesting that you say that the Gimp has great support for PSD. I have had a lot of problems loading any PSD files with the Gimp, at least under Linux (I don't really use MS-Windows). Now on the other hand I have more luck with convert to convert PSD files, something like this: `convert sample.psd[0] sample.jpg`. The `[0]` index is to get the resulting image (all the layers merged on in image.)

Comment: The [0] index is to get the resulting image (all the layers merged on in image.)  ....... GREAT! Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have just created a Node module that deals with PSD files from the CLI. You may use it with as many files as you want with just one command.

As far as my tests went, GIMP is not really a solution and has a poor understanding of modern PSD files, and NodeJS happen to have a great new package that deals with the Photoshop format.

Instructions from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kartsims/psd-cli):

Install it:

`npm install -g psd-cli`

Convert `myfile.psd` to a new `myfile.png` :

`psd myfile.psd`

I hope you find this useful! The package is pretty new and other cool features will be added soon. Any feature requests and help with improving the code is appreciated :)

Comment: ooh fancy, thanks for the update. indeed the gimp situation was "mildly workable" but far from optimal plus the license with psd.js is nicer.

Comment: Currently it does nothing, but `convert` works.

Comment: Looks like this project is not maintained anymore.