# Compress all files to the "9" level with gimp

Tags: linux, batch, compression, gimp, file-format

I created the scripts from [Using Gimp to batch convert images to another format in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/77429/using-gimp-to-batch-convert-images-to-another-format-in-windows#77445) tip made by @forrest-voight. Can anyone tell me how I can add options to this script so that the maximum compression (9) for each file is applied immediately ?

script . scm :

```
(define (myconvert in_filename out_filename)
    (let* (
            (image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE in_filename in_filename)))
            (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image)))
        )
        (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable out_filename out_filename)
        (gimp-image-delete image)
    )
)
```

command in terminnal:

```
for A in * ; do gimp -i -b "(myconvert \"$A\" \"$A.jpg\")" -b '(gimp-quit 0)' ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to export as PNG, use **file-png-save** or **file-png-save2** instead of **gimp-file-save** obviously you will have to set all the parameters accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I noticed though that the files can be much lighter. With https://tinypng.com/ the compression is much higher. Are there any ways / programs to do this in the console on Linux?

Comment: As it's usual to use imagemagick to do batch image processing on Linux you could try there, and the help does mention some non-ImageMagick png compression tools: https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#png_non-im